# Background slides when entering letter in form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

When looking at my website today, I noticed something strange. When clicking on an input field an entering one letter, the background slides a little bit. Unfortunately I do not know, why this is the case.

For making it more clear, here is a (poor-quality) GIF: http://makeagif.com/i/FRMlyL

JSFiddle link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pesrd/

Maybe this is a well-known issue but I never had to deal with that.

Comment: Forgot that. Seems like that only occurs in Chrome (21.0.1180.83 m)...
I just tested Opera and Firefox without any issues.

Comment: Also couln't reproduce on Chrome 23

Comment: Check for browser plugins, such as a form auto complete plugin or something similar.

Comment: I just deactivated anything running on my Chrome and the slide still appears...

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Chrome 22beta.

Comment: reproduced with chrome 21.0.1180.82. I could also prevent the slide when messing with the css rules for .rightSide in the chrome console (uncheck position: absolute for example).

Comment: Also couln't reproduce on Chrome 21.0.1180.89

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 22.0.1229.79

Comment: that was barely noticeable, had you not said it I would have not noticed it!